# airflow mysql_hook No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: python, airflow

I got

> No module named 'MySQLdb'

when importing ariflow

> from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook

I'm using Mac, python 3.7.6

Installed

1. pip install 'apache-airflow[mysql]'
2. pip install apache-airflow
3. PyMySQL==0.10.1
4. marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.23.1
5. mysql-connector-python==8.0.22
6. mysqlclient==1.3.14

Beside this specific issue, we have a server installed airflow and I was tring to test some airflow components (hooks etc) without full airflow environment, is that feasible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not using the updated `MySqlHook`.

For `Airflow <2.0` you will need to install [backport providers](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-mysql/) :

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-mysql
```

For `Airflow >=2.0` you will need to install [providers](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-mysql
```

then you can import the hook via:

```
from airflow.providers.mysql.hooks.mysql import MySqlHook
```

As for your second question i'm not sure what you mean by full airflow environment. The providers for example were removed from Airflow core to separated packages.

Comment: With "full airflow environment" I mean a fully functional airflow environment which I'm not running a airflow instance but only testing the components Hooks etc